# How to enable long descriptions on doxygen?

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard

I'm using doxygen for my C code project
and would like to hide the "More..." link on function description and just show the entire text.
How? :)

[image: More...]

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? The "More..."  in the brief description signals that there is a more extensive documentation of the function and by clicking on it you will see this text. It is not possible unless you would be able to cramp all the information into the brief description (will in 99.9999% of the cases mot possible). A possibility might be to have a look at the "layout possibilities" of doxygen (see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout) disable the brief description and only show the detailed description.

Comment: Using doxygen GUI 1.9.6

Answer (score 0):

Enable "ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC"

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your answer and also share the result of the "Condensed" "Show configuration" from the "Run tab" in your answer. Also a small piece of source code showing the issue in the question would be useful.